# (Python 2.7.6) IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: OSX Yosemite

Tags: macos, terminal, directory, ioerror

Sorry first time doing this -
Essentially I have obtained a code that can convert .wav audio files to an .stl file. I am trying to run "wavtotext.py" in Terminal, but end up with this IOError no file or directory error.

Can anyone please help?

```
Last login: Wed Mar 18 22:27:04 on ttys001
/var/folders/1_/q5syr5b51zn6y9yvxd7v8mhw0000gn/T/Cleanup\ At\ Startup/wavtotext-448370838.054.py.command ; exit;
Jags-MacBook-Pro:~ jag$ /var/folders/1_/q5syr5b51zn6y9yvxd7v8mhw0000gn/T/Cleanup\ At\ Startup/wavtotext-448370838.054.py.command ; exit;
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/private/var/folders/1_/q5syr5b51zn6y9yvxd7v8mhw0000gn/T/Cleanup At Startup/wavtotext-448370838.051.py", line 24, in <module>
     w = wave.open(fileName, 'r')
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/wave.py", line 502, in open
     return Wave_read(f)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/wave.py", line 159, in __init__
     f = __builtin__.open(f, 'rb')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'yourbody.wav'
logout

[Process completed]
```

This is my code:

```
import wave
import math
import struct

bitDepth = 8#target bitDepth
frate = 44100#target frame rate

fileName = "yourbody.wav"#file to be imported (change this)

#read file and get data
w = wave.open(fileName, 'r')
numframes = w.getnframes()

frame = w.readframes(numframes)#w.getnframes()

frameInt = map(ord, list(frame))#turn into array

#separate left and right channels and merge bytes
frameOneChannel = [0]*numframes#initialize list of one channel of wave
for i in range(numframes):
    frameOneChannel[i] = frameInt[4*i+1]*2**8+frameInt[4*i]#separate channels     and store one channel in new list
    if frameOneChannel[i] > 2**15:
        frameOneChannel[i] = (frameOneChannel[i]-2**16)
    elif frameOneChannel[i] == 2**15:
        frameOneChannel[i] = 0
    else:
        frameOneChannel[i] = frameOneChannel[i]

#convert to string
audioStr = ''
for i in range(numframes):
    audioStr += str(frameOneChannel[i])
    audioStr += ","#separate elements with comma

fileName = fileName[:-3]#remove .wav extension
text_file = open(fileName+"txt", "w")
text_file.write("%s"%audioStr)
text_file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'yourbody.wav'

The file 'yourbody.wav' is not found in the directory where you executed your program.

Comment: I have the file 'yourbody.wav' in the same folder as the wavtotxt.py file. I am viewing the wavtotxt.py file in TextWrangler, and running it in Terminal. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: according to your error message，your Python file is at File "/private/var/folders/1_/q5syr5b51zn6y9yvxd7v8mhw0000gn/T/Cleanup At Startup/wavtotext-448370838.051.py". try go to the folder where you keep your files in terminal and do python wavtotext.py